# Parse Json from file

Tags: json, angular

I have service to parse json

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  private tsUrl = './../Test/test.json';
  data: Object;

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getTest(): Observable<any>  {
    return this.http.get(this.tsUrl)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

But When I call this in my component

```
  private p: any;

  constructor(private testService : TestService ) {
    this.p =this.testService .getTest().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
      };

    console.log(this.p);
 }
```

it logs:
[image]

What can I do?

And am I doing parse from json file right? File path is correct

@echonax solved my problem but now I see this error message

[image]

Comment: You need to import map `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: There's a space here: `this.testService .getTest()` intended?

Comment: @echonax that's no problem. I inspected my error and map without json `.map(res => res);` and it seems I'm receiving html instead of `json` see here http://i.imgur.com/PihuLCZ.png

Comment: my json file is in file system

Comment: The `unexpected token` refers to malformed JSON. Check how your data looks like in the mapping: `.map((res: Response) => { console.log('res', res); })`

Comment: @AJT_82 it logs this http://i.imgur.com/PihuLCZ.png and it's my main page. so it can't access to json file?

Comment: Yeah, well then you have the issue there. It's not returning JSON, but apparently some html code :)

Comment: don't you know how to solve that? :/

Comment: I think the issue is that you are using a relative path, `./../Test/test.json`, and it doing request to exactly that, which does not exist. Type the actual path, something like `/path/path/Test/test.json`.